# Populate navigation tree with data from file

Tags: jquery, tree, navigation, populate

I'm having difficulties with my school project.
I have to implement a javascript module for independent software from which cannot even read from database. In my module I have to implement navigation menu which drops down and inside has 3 levels of dropdowns and every have minimum 3 children.

I can't get the data from the software, but in upgrade I made export every time the module upgrades to generate a file with the menu data. But cannot populate it in my module.

The data is now like:

```
1 name
1.1 child name
1.2 child name
1.3 child name
2
2.1 child name
2.2 child name
....
3....
3.1...
3.2...
```

and so on..
Is there any possibility to read that file with jquery and populate my menu and is it going to be fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried jquery [.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method?

```
$.get( "data.txt", function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
    // build menu from data..
});
```